# Why does my Nikon sb900 have a delayed response?

Tags: flash, troubleshooting

I am new to the use of flash.  I have a Nikon d300s and I am using it with the sb900 flash.

After pushing the shutter button to fire, the sb900 makes 3 little clicking noises, then fires.  I want to capture people moving in low light situations and I am afraid that this delay will make me lose the shot.  This happens both in TTL and Manual mode.

Is this normal or did I it set up something incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you simply have red-eye reduction turned on. The flash fires a few 'pre-flashes' which makes the iris of your subject's eyes close. This stops too much light being reflected back from the retina when the main flash is fired. Just change the relevant setting on your camera.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see if you have it set to first curtain sync or second curtain sync. Some effects require delaying the flash as the shutter ends rather than opens. If you have a long shutter then this becomes more obvious.